# webrequest.GetResponse https throw error 403 protocolerror on windows 2008 x64

Tags: .net, https, webrequest, http-status-code-403

I have a application use Webrequest to post and get some data from a server with a SSL certificate. It is all very well except on Windows 2008 x64. The server return error 403 forbidden.

thanks in advance.

burns

Comment: So, does it work thru a normal browser or other app?

Comment: Yes, it is very on windows 7, window xp, visual studio 2008,but moved to Windows 2008 server, the problem occured.

Answer (score 1):

After several debug, I found that is X509Certificate problem. does have the different behavior between window x32 and x64 with X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Path);  Webrequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert)?